# Can I Import an existing OpenPGP key into Ubuntu for use as my Personal key?

Tags: gnupg, launchpad, openpgp, keyserver, keychain

```
    louis@WinNyx:~$ gpg --send-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 1FDBB6475ED8B730113953BE5CD637DC9222E537
    gpg: sending key 5CD637DC9222E537 to hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com

    louis@WinNyx:~$ gpg -k
    /home/louis/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
        ------------------------------
        pub   ed25519 2020-08-30 [SC]
              DACC660A9C2DB3A19CC5B2512BA791DE0CA69C40
        uid           [ unknown] louis@waweru.me <louis@waweru.me>
        sub   cv25519 2020-08-30 [E]
        
        pub   ed25519 2021-03-14 [SC]
              1FDBB6475ED8B730113953BE5CD637DC9222E537
        uid           [ultimate] louis@waweru.me <louis@waweru.me>
        uid           [ultimate] Louis A. Waweru <louis@waweru.me>
        sub   cv25519 2021-03-14 [E]

    louis@WinNyx:~$ gpg --search-keys --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com 1FDBB6475ED8B730113953BE5CD637DC9222E537
    gpg: data source: https://162.213.33.8:443
    (1)     louis@waweru.me <louis@waweru.me>
            Louis A. Waweru <louis@waweru.me>
              263 bit EDDSA key 5CD637DC9222E537, created: 2021-03-14
    Keys 1-1 of 1 for "1FDBB6475ED8B730113953BE5CD637DC9222E537".  Enter number(s), N)ext, or Q)uit > 1
gpg: key 5CD637DC9222E537: "louis@waweru.me <louis@waweru.me>" 2 new signatures
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:         new signatures: 2
```

Yet on launchpad, after several days:

[image: launchpad could not import key]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launchpad does not yet support Ed25519 OpenPGP keys, due to problems with upgrading to GnuPG v2 that we need to sort out at some point.  See [bug 1827369](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1827369).  In the meantime, you'll have to use a key type that's supported by GnuPG v1.

Comment: Thank you, saved me a ton of head scratching

Comment: Oh, and thank you for all of your work!

Answer (score 2):

Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy/paste the text directly.

Anyway, the problem is **your key needs to be in the Ubuntu keyserver** for Launchpad to import it. You uploaded the key to `hkps://keys.openpgp.org`, which is not part of the SKS pool so the key will never propagate to the Ubuntu keyserver.

You should instead upload the key directly to `hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com` then wait ten minutes before trying to import it to Launchpad.

### EDIT

"Personal keys" are those for which you have the private key. These will also be displayed when you enter the command `gpg -K`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will clean up the question. Looks like I don't have the private key as `gpg -K` doesn't return any output. Thank you.

Comment: Waited quite a while and it still won’t let me import it from Launchpad. Thanks for your help. I think I may be asking the wrong question